# Reduce Loading Time of 0.chunk.js in React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node-modules

I am creating a react app. There is a js file **0.chunk.js** having size around **1.5 MB**, and it takes over **30s** to load which delayed my app to load. 
I want to know how can i reduce the loading time?

I am using **jsPDF** and **html2canvas** to generate some pdf and it seems it increasing the size of chunk i-e 1.5MB. I am already using **Webpack**. I have also created a seperate component for pdf generation.

Is there any way i can reduce more the chunk size?

Comment: check your package.json and remove unnecessary packages. it can help you for reduce loading time. you can use this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map-explorer)

Comment: You can refer to lazy and Suspence in React. https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **React Router** concept and by setting the conditional import statement you can prevent unwanted loading of files. It will be loaded only when we need